# Kotlin - add a single space between string and number

Tags: kotlin

I have the following texts. I need to add a single space between the string and numbers.

```
Text1 -> Text 1

Text10 -> Text 10

Kotlin2 -> Kotlin 2
```

I used the following code, but it does not work.

```
fun addSpace(text: String): String {
   return text.split("\\D".toRegex()).joinToString(separator = " ") { it  }
}
```

It return only the number.

Comment: To add to the actual answers: the reason this code fails is because it's splitting _on_ non-digits and hence discarding them, leaving only the digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just replace any occurrence of a string of digits with a space followed by those digits:

```
fun addSpace(text: String) = text.replace(Regex("\\d+" ), " \$0")
```

(The `$` is escaped so that the Kotlin compiler doesn't treat it as interpolation.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex groups and replaceAll

```
fun main() {
    val input = "Text1 Text10 Kotlin2"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll("$1 $2")
    println(matcher)
}
```

Output will be

`Text 1 Text 10 Kotlin 2`